# Separate delimited field into multiple rows, in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a data frame DF in R with the format:

DF:

```
col1  col2  col3  
ID1   ID2   apple, pear, banana  
ID3   ID4   pear, orange  
........
```

and I would like to convert it to DF1, but pivoting col3 into multiple rows, with one element in each:

DF1:

```
col1  col2  col3  
ID1   ID2   apple  
ID1   ID2   pear  
ID1   ID2   banana  
ID3   ID4   pear  
ID3   ID4   orange  
....
```

Any function that does this, either from *base* or another package, for a general delimiter would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you go the tidyverse route, use [`tidyr::separate_longer_delim`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_longer_delim.html).  (`separate_rows` is [superseded](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html).)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  separate_rows(col3)
```

Comment: thanks Chris. I take you have to define the separator?  Such as: df1 <- df%>%separate_rows(col3, sep=",")

Comment: No you don't have to, only if it's **not**  a `,`, or `;`, or a whitespace do you have to specifiy the delimiter or , more generally, the regex pattern by which to split

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` is needed for either of these solutions

```
library(tidyverse)
```

There is the `separate_longer_delim()` function like so:

```
df1 <- separate_longer_delim(df,col3,delim=",")
```

Or you could use `unnest` function like so:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(col3=strsplit(col3, ",")) %>%
    unnest(col3)
```